# Using / Mocking Request.Url when using MvcContrib TestHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd, mvccontrib

I'm using MvcContrib.TestHelper, and initialize my controller like this:

```
var accountController = new AccountController();

var builder = new TestControllerBuilder();
builder.InitializeController(accountController);
```

My problem is, that inside my `AccountController` I have:

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

However, this comes back as null. Request is a proxy.

How can I set this up from my unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has probably already been solved, but what worked for me was to use a mocking framework (like [RhinoMocks](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks)):

```
var contextMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
contextMock.Expect(x => x.Request).Return(new FakeHttpRequest("SOME_RELATIVE_URL", new Uri("http://to.somewhere.com"), new Uri("http://from.somewhere.com")));

controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = contextMock;
```